# html - verify that each div will be on separated print page

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have many divs that proposed to be printed - on different pages.
How can I make sure that when the user is clicking the print button, each div will be on a different page?

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear question describe with some codes if it's possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`page-break-after` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) in the `print` [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). The advantage is, that you don't have to change the size of your divs, it just makes sure that the page break will be after the div.

```
@media print {
    div {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

More [information about `page-break-after` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after).

Comment: That solved my problem ! Thanks.
How can I now ensure that a div in this page will be completely on a page (i don`t want a div to be catted between 2 pages)?

Comment: You can't, if the content length is not known. Maybe you can set a smaller `font-size` for your divs in the print media query...

Answer (score 1):

In css, there is a media query you can use to specifically format your web page for when you want to print it:

```
@media print {
  /* insert your style declarations here */
  div {
    page-break-after: always; /* ensures the next will we appear on new page */
  }
}
```

You can use this media query to make each div fill up an entire page when the user decides to print. You can use this to modify things like removing the navbar when the user decides to print.

On the other hand, to avoid direct breaks after a certain element use `page-break-after: avoid;`

You can also for the use to print in a certain format that you want to specify using the follow:

```
@page {
  size: A4; /* or A4 landscape or A5 */
}
```

Comment: The viewport height and width will not be useful here, because it doesn't represent the page size...

Comment: @Andreas is there anything the represents the printed page size in css?

Comment: width and height destroyed the pages